# Enable dragging on leaflet map for popup div within map

Tags: leaflet, events

I'm sorry for my English, I just study it.
Is it possible to save map-draggable functionality on popup within leaflet map? I mean move the map while dragging(clicking and moving or tuching on mobile) across the popup?

Comment: Save where: on users computer, on server?

Comment: No, I meant to keep the functionality of moving the map when clicking/dragging on the popup. By default, the map does not move when you click/drag on the popup area, it moves only when you click/drag on the map itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable dragging the whole map when mouse is pressed on popup by making popup content ignore the mouse events.

This can be achieved by modifying appropriate Leaflet CSS styles:

```
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
   pointer-events: none;
}
.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works well. But what if popup has a button? Button will not be working too. I need this behavior only on mobiles. Can this be done with JS and events? I try until it works.

Comment: Popup close button will be working, it's in a separate `div` element with `leaflet-popup-close-button` CSS class.

Comment: I have another button on popup and big clickable image. I add CSS property to them "pointer-events: auto" and it works... But not so pretty. Is it possible for the entire area of popup (with button and clickable image) to be with draggable map, but click events work?

Comment: It would probably be possible, but with a lot of event processing.